# Actionscript 3: Endianness of bytearray via websocket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, websocket, arrays

I store audio recorded from the microphone in a bytearray and send it via the AS3Websocket library (https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket) to a server:

```
private function processMicInput(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    if (isRecording) {
        while (event.data.bytesAvailable) {
            recordingBuffer.writeShort(event.data.readFloat()*0x7fff);
        }
        websocket.sendBytes(recordingBuffer);
        recordingBuffer.clear();
    }
}
```

However, I want the data to be little-endian. It doesn't seem to matter whether I set the `recordingBuffer` bytearray to little-endian or big-endian, it always gets sent as big-endian.
Internally, it seems that the AS3Websocket library uses a socket that is set to big-endian. Is this the problem?
If so, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting.  In the library under sendBytes you can see that the data gets copied to [two](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket/blob/master/AS3WebSocket/src/com/worlize/websocket/WebSocket.as#L374) [buffers](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket/blob/master/AS3WebSocket/src/com/worlize/websocket/WebSocket.as#L389) on its way out.  I'm not sure it's safe to modify what's happening in the library.  You could change the order of the bytes as you write them into recordingBuffer:

```
    while (event.data.bytesAvailable) {
        var val:int = event.data.readFloat()*0x7fff;
        recordingBuffer.writeShort( ((val >> 8) & 0xff) | ((val & 0xff) << 8));
    }
```

If you need to flip whole 32-bit words, you'll have to get fancier.  LMK if this is the case.

Good luck!

Comment: You did it! Thanks, I was struggling with this for hours :)
Now, I am not sure however what the endianness of bytebuffers means, as I thought that it meant exactly what you now did manually.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the endianness wasn't working.  Did you set it before the while loop?  It should have modified how the .writeShort call wrote bytes into the bytearray.

Comment: It seems that the endianness of the bytearray gets reset to big-endian every time sendBytes is called.